# Appending file_name part to each line of the file, recursively to multiple files

Tags: bash, terminal, file-manipulation

So, I have multiple files of the form

```
filename_date.csv
```

in a folder, for example something like

```
filename_2010_01_01.csv
```

that files contains, say... 1000 rows with a format like this

```
37845287|2364532467|237849853
04568750|89345735385|94573857
```

But I have 365 files like this for the whole year, one for each day. What I'd like to do is to make some kind of bash? script maybe that takes the date from the filename and appends it to the end of each of the x lines in each file so the result would be something like

filename_2010_01_01.csv

```
37845287|2364532467|237849853|2010_01_01
04568750|89345735385|94573857|2010_01_01
```

filename_2010_01_02.csv

```
438574|563546567|2342523525|2010_01_02
326345452|456454763|7856763|2010_01_02
```

So far what I've tried:

I tried with this

```
sed 's/$/|2010-01-01/' filename_2010-01-01.csv > filename_2010-01-01.csv
```

that works for a single file.

Now I'm trying the following loop

```
FILES=~/Desktop/2010/byday/*
for f in $FILES
do
  filename=$f | cut -d'/' -f7-
done
```

Once I have the name of the file there, I can just add the sed command within the loop but I'm having trouble on making the `filename` var to take the value of the command

If I just echo the command within the loop it does get me the filename, that command is only to strip the path from the filename.

UPDATE:

Inside the loop

```
  filename=`basename $f`
```

that shorter, cleaner and the variable actually gets the value

UPDATE 2:

This loop

```
FILES=~/Desktop/2010/byday/*
for f in $FILES
do
  fname=`basename $f`
  fname=${fname%.csv}
  fname=${fname##filename_}
  echo $fname
  sed 's/$/|$fname/' filename_$fname.csv > filename__$fname.csv
done
```

Actually outputs correctly the date BUT there's something in the sed command that deletes the content of the file

UPDATE 3:

With this Im almost there

```
FILES=~/Desktop/2010/byday/*
for f in $FILES
do
  fname=`basename $f`
  fname=${fname%.csv}
  fname=${fname##partitioned.csvmerged_}
  sed 's/$/|$fname/' partitioned.csvmerged_${fname}.csv > $fname.csv
done
```

It writes a new file with just the date as filename (which is good) but Im not sure how should I interpolate the var there since with this the output inside the file is

```
438574|563546567|2342523525|$fname
326345452|456454763|7856763|$fname
```

Comment: efforts added to the question

Comment: I saw that, Im writing to a new file now... but have a problem with the var interpolation. Can you take a look at UPDATE 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the same file that you are reading. As soon as the shell parses the command, it starts truncating the file and then, with the output file prepared, it starts the `sed` command, that finds an empty file. Your problem will be solved by avoiding the redirection and using the `-i` parameter in `sed`:

```
FILES=~/Desktop/2010/byday/*
for f in $FILES
do
    fname=$(basename "$f" .csv)
    fname=${fname##filename_}
    echo "$fname"
    sed -i "s/\$/|$fname/" "filename_$fname.csv"
done
```

I also added a few minor changes, like using the already present `basename` to get rid of the extension, quoting variables and solving your next problem: not having `$fname` expanded due to the use of single quotes.

Comment: If there's something wrong, tell me, so I can rewrite the answer to make it valid for everyone else

Comment: the -i parameter gave me an error something like "characters after p command".

this line worked for me 

`sed "s/$/|$fname/" filename_${fname}.csv > $fname.csv`

Comment: Weird. `-i` just means to edit the file in place. And there's no `p` command anywhere :-?

Comment: yeah. I search for p in the code and didn't find anything either. Maybe the escaping of `$` on your answer vs mine without scaping ?